# Show just a sample of text in search results

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm using ReactiveSearch (great Search UI library!) and am trying to figure out how I can just show a ample of a text article in the ReactiveList search results. Currently it shows the whole article but I just want the first 250 words or so to be displayed.

[image]

I just want say the first 250 words of that. Is that possible with ReactiveList? If so, how can I go about doing that or is there a feature o setting that I'm missing with ReactiveSearch?

This is the simple line that displays it currently:

```
<p className="card-text">{data.Text}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to truncate the text after a few lines. But `ReactiveSearch` doesn't support this feature on the library level.

You can achieve this by using the package called `react-truncate`. You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/One-com/react-truncate).

Hope this helps!